# Parsing imported CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to parse a .csv file using the Import-CSV commandlet as shown below:

```
$lease_import = ipcsv -Path 'C:\leases.csv'-Delimiter "," | where { 
        ($_.binding_state -ne "ABANDONED") -and ($_.mac_address -ne "") -and (($_.ends -replace "T"," " )-match "2014")
}
```

A general 'ends' field in this CSV looks like this: `2014-01-23T13:49:38.000Z`. I want to replace the 'T' with a space and I want to replace `.000Z` with an empty string. Finally, the dashes would have to get replaced by a /. End result would have to be something along the lines of this:

```
2014/01/23 13:49:38
```

I tried starting simple by using -replace to change the "T" to a space following this link: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/21/use-powershell-to-replace-text-in-strings.aspx. However, this doesn't work for me.

Am I trying to do too much at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be more elegant solutions by trying to parse the DateTime out of the string but a very simple one would be

```
("2014-01-23T13:49:38.000Z".TrimEnd(".000Z") -Replace "T"," ") -replace "-","/"
```

which would return

```
2014/01/23 13:49:38
```

In your loop this would look like

```
($_.ends.TrimEnd(".000Z") -Replace "T"," ") -replace "-","/"
```

In place of `.TrimEnd()` you could just do another `Replace` but since `TrimEnd` is there to remove trailing characters why  not use it.

I did try to use something like `[datetime]::ParseExact` but they need to have clean strings with not extra data else you get parsing errors. You can clean the string like we have with the `-replace`'s but then it becomes redundant to use the function. Someone else might have a cleaner approach

Comment: I'm sorry, it works perfectly, but I am a bit confused on how to integrate that into the Import-CSV. Are you referring to a new, different loop?

Comment: @Simplexity you dont really say what you wanted to do so i cant answer that. What are you doing with the data?

Comment: My bad, I made an obvious mistake. One last question; How would I use TrimEnd() to delete the last 6 characters (assuming the first two would be random)?

Comment: @Simplexity is there always a period in that string? Everything after changes?

Comment: I figured it out already :) Used -replace instead with a wildcard. Thanks a bunch!